# Understanding Consensus Protocols in Blockchain for IoT: Seeking Clarity on Implementation

Tags: blockchain, iot, distributed-computing, consensus

I'm writing a research proposal on blockchain in IoT.
I'm still grappling with a fundamental question: **Where exactly is consensus needed in the IoT architecture?** While I've encountered various use cases, many of them explain the implementation rather broadly and vaguely, leaving me somewhat puzzled.

I've been diving deep into the world of consensus protocols in blockchain, particularly with a focus on IoT networks. While researching, I've come across some insightful papers like the ones listed below:

1. Salimitari, M. and Chatterjee, M., 2018. A survey on consensus protocols in blockchain for IoT networks. [Link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.05613)
2. Jie Xu, Cong Wang, and Xiaohua Jia. 2023. A Survey of Blockchain Consensus Protocols. [Link](https://doi.org/10.1145/3579845)
3. Sivleen Kaur, Sheetal Chaturvedi, Aabha Sharma, Jayaprakash Kar, "A Research Survey on Applications of Consensus Protocols in Blockchain", [Link](https://doi.org/10.1155/2021/6693731)

These papers have shed light on the critical aspects of consensus protocols that are vital for IoT implementations within the blockchain ecosystem. Key takeaways include the need for high performance, throughput, scalability, and data privacy when designing consensus protocols for IoT in blockchain. It's also worth noting that hybrid frameworks appear to hold promise for achieving these objectives effectively.

If any of you have thoughts or insights to share, I'd greatly appreciate it. **It would be immensely helpful if you could elaborate on a specific use case or example, considering the architecture and data flow involved.** Understanding real-world scenarios where consensus protocols come into play within IoT setups would be a fantastic way to solidify my understanding.
Also any helpful articles/research papers/links would be appreciated.

Looking forward to your insights!